# Why upper bound wildcard works in the following example

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}

class A<T> {
    T t;

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    T getT() {
        return t;
    }
}

    public static void print1(A<? extends Animal> obj){
        //obj.setT(new Cat()); //Line 1
        System.out.println(obj.getT().getClass());

    }


    public static void print2(A<? super Animal> obj){
        obj.setT(new Dog()); //Line 2
        System.out.println(obj.getT().getClass());

    }
```

I understand why line 1 does not compile, but do not understand at all why Line 2 compiles.

I'm trying to understand lower and upper bound wildcard in Java

Comment: `A<? super Animal>` only accepts classes that are SUPER of Animal. `Dog` is a child of `Animal`

Comment: So Dog should not be accepted in Line 2, right?

Comment: Is this your actual code or just a summary? `print1` and `print2` are outside of the class body and that's not allowed.

Comment: It is a summary but yes, normaly print1 & print2 are inside a main function.

Comment: So inside ``print1()`` method, I cannot call the ``setter()`` on ``obj`` ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java generics, A<? extends Animal> is a declaration of a wildcard type with an upper bound. It means that the type parameter T can be any type that is a subtype of Animal (including Animal itself). When you have a wildcard with an upper bound, it ensures that the type is "read-only" in the sense that you can only retrieve values of type T but you cannot modify the contents.

In the print1 method, obj is declared with an upper bound wildcard A<? extends Animal>. This means that you can call the getT() method, which returns a value of type T (which is some subtype of Animal), but you cannot call the setT() method because the exact type of T is not known. The compiler cannot guarantee the safety of assigning a Cat to T because T could be a more specific subtype of Animal, such as Dog.

On the other hand, A<? super Animal> is a declaration of a wildcard type with a lower bound. It means that the type parameter T can be any supertype of Animal (including Animal itself). When you have a wildcard with a lower bound, it allows you to both retrieve and modify the contents of the object.

In the print2 method, obj is declared with a lower bound wildcard A<? super Animal>. This means that you can call both the getT() and setT() methods. The setT() method accepts any subtype of Animal (including Animal itself) because any such subtype is a valid assignment to T (which could be a supertype of Animal). In this case, you can assign a Dog to T because T can be a supertype of Dog (e.g., Animal).